# Using input parameters directly in a function is much slower than putting them into local variables and using local variables

Tags: oracle, performance, parameters, local-variables

I was very surprised when I experienced that a basically very fast query became extremely slow when I put it into a function and used the input parameters in the 'where' condition.

Then, in the function, I declared local variables, for each input parameter a distinct local variable with the same type and put the value of each input parameter into the corresponding local variable, and in the 'where' condition of the query I used the local variable. In this way, the function became as fast as the query itself when I wrote literals into the 'where' condition.

I Illustrate this with a simple example (of course my real function is more complicated)

```
create or replace function func_slow(par_number int) return int
as
cnt int;
begin
  select count(*) into cnt from MyTable where code > par_number;
  return cnt;
end;

create or replace function func_fast(par_number int) return int
as
cnt int;
loc_number int;
begin
  loc_number := par_number;
  select count(*) into cnt from MyTable where code > loc_number;
  return cnt;
end;
```

What is the explanation of this phenomenon?

### EDIT

Since some doubts emerged about the validity of this issue, I copy here the complete codes that actually exhibit the phenomenon. The fast function completes in 0.5 seconds while the slow more than 1 minute (I cancelled always after 1 minute).

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION func_slow_complete_trunc
    (par_MINIVALUE number, par_MAXIVALUE number, par_charact_refnum int) return int
as
cnt int;
begin
        select tlvd_cnt into cnt from (
        select count(distinct TLVD.id) tlvd_cnt from trc, tlvd where trc.charact_refnum = par_charact_refnum and tlvd.tbidavis2_id = trc.tbidavis2_id and tlvd.lvd = 1 and tlvd.lvddate>sysdate
        and TRC.MAXIVALUE >= par_MINIVALUE and  TRC.MINIVALUE <= par_MAXIVALUE
         and exists(select * from "libisatz" where "libisatz".TBIDAVIS2_ID=TLVD.TBIDAVIS2_ID) 
        );
return cnt;
end;

CREATE or replace FUNCTION func_fast_complete_trunc
    (par_MINIVALUE number, par_MAXIVALUE number, par_charact_refnum int) return int
as
cnt int;    
loc_MINIVALUE number; loc_MAXIVALUE number; loc_charact_refnum int;

begin
        loc_MINIVALUE := par_MINIVALUE;   
    loc_MAXIVALUE := par_MAXIVALUE;
        loc_charact_refnum:= par_charact_refnum;

        select tlvd_cnt into cnt from (
        select count(distinct TLVD.id) tlvd_cnt from trc, tlvd where trc.charact_refnum = loc_charact_refnum and tlvd.tbidavis2_id = trc.tbidavis2_id and tlvd.lvd = 1 and tlvd.lvddate>sysdate
        and TRC.MAXIVALUE >= loc_MINIVALUE and  TRC.MINIVALUE <= loc_MAXIVALUE
         and exists(select * from "libisatz" where "libisatz".TBIDAVIS2_ID=TLVD.TBIDAVIS2_ID) 
        );
return cnt;
end;
```

The testing queries were

```
select func_slow_complete_trunc(42,42, -10000201) from onerow
select func_fast_complete_trunc(42,42, -10000201) from onerow
```

### EDIT 2

I found that the trouble is in TRC:

[image]

And I also observed that instead of using local variables, it's enough to insert a `+ 0` to any place of the `where` clause where it has sense, this change makes the slow function as fast as the "fast" function (which uses local variables).**

**And what's more, it can be enough to place some spaces into the code!**

E.g. this code is already fast !!!:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION func_slow_complete_trunc
    (par_MINIVALUE number, par_MAXIVALUE number, par_charact_refnum int) return int
as
cnt int;
begin
        select tlvd_cnt into cnt from (
        select count(distinct TLVD.id) tlvd_cnt from trc, tlvd where trc.charact_refnum  = par_charact_refnum  and tlvd.tbidavis2_id  = trc.tbidavis2_id  and tlvd.lvd = 1 and tlvd.lvddate >sysdate 
        and TRC.MAXIVALUE >= par_MINIVALUE and  TRC.MINIVALUE  <= par_MAXIVALUE
         and exists(select * from "libisatz" where "libisatz".TBIDAVIS2_ID =TLVD.TBIDAVIS2_ID) 
        );
return cnt;
end;
```

, while the original code keeps being slow!

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It may be that you first called func_slow, then func_fast. The second call will be faster because of caching in the database server.

Comment: No, this is independent of the order of calling.

Comment: how many rows in the table? index? how many seconds is 'basically very fast', and 'very slow' ? How much variation in the several tests?

Comment: Those two function versions will NOT produce a difference in performance. Something else you did that is not included in your example above must be responsible.

Comment: For performance related questions it's absolutely required to have an execution plan. Otherwise it's just a guessing game, because two versions of code have no difference in the processing flow.

Comment: @astentx SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY); gives the same result, independently of the content of the function. How can I refine the plan?

Comment: @mma You probably need to look at the explain plans of the *recursive* SQL statements inside the function, not the plan of the main SQL. To do that, find the SQL_ID and then use DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR like this: `select * from gv$sql where sql_fulltext like '%CONNECT%'; select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'SQL_ID from above'));`  But I have a feeling that won't be enough, and that something really weird is happening here. You may need to post a fully reproducible example, including DDL, sample data, and version number. That process can take hours but may be necessary.

Comment: @mma If adding spaces to the code changes performance, this is likely a plan management issue. Many Oracle tuning tools operate on the SQL_ID, which is like an MD5 hash of the SQL text. So if you change a single character of the SQL text, the optimizer treats the code like a brand new statement. Any plan management fixes, like a SQL profile, or plan outline, will not be applied to the new statement. Maybe a DBA tuned an old statement with an `/*+ INDEX... */` hint, but that hint isn't carried over to the new statement. Compare the `Note` sections in the `DBMS_XPLAN` output.