# How can I get rid of the bad execution plans in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Recently I faced with the problem that some (theoretically irrelevant) formal changes in the code of a function (even adding or removing a space character to or from the code) can greatly affect the performance of the function. (see my previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337934/using-input-parameters-directly-in-a-function-is-much-slower-than-putting-them-i) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75362360/how-can-spaces-in-the-code-affect-the-performance-in-oracle)).

The mystery was solved by Jon Heller [as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337934/using-input-parameters-directly-in-a-function-is-much-slower-than-putting-them-i?noredirect=1#comment132981645_75337934)

> If adding spaces to the code changes performance, this is likely a
> plan management issue. Many Oracle tuning tools operate on the SQL_ID,
> which is like an MD5 hash of the SQL text. So if you change a single
> character of the SQL text, the optimizer treats the code like a brand
> new statement. Any plan management fixes, like a SQL profile, or plan
> outline, will not be applied to the new statement. Maybe a DBA tuned
> an old statement with an /*+ INDEX... */ hint, but that hint isn't
> carried over to the new statement. Compare the Note sections in the
> DBMS_XPLAN output.

and [as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75362360/how-can-spaces-in-the-code-affect-the-performance-in-oracle?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment132990046_75362360)

> A space in a SQL statement would change the SQL_ID, which could cause
> the optimizer to no longer match the SQL statement with plan
> management features like profiles, outlines, baselines (possibly -
> they're supposed to be able to avoid this problem in some cases),
> patches, advanced rewrites, etc.

So the only question I have left is how can I get rid of the stuck bad execution plans? How can I "clean" Oracle from them?

Comment: You need to get two actual execution plans (for example by `dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor(...)` providing sid and serial number) and check if two plans are really different. Then check `dba_outlines` for the SQL text containing your objects. Or check `OTHER_XML` column of [`V$SQL_PLAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SQL_PLAN.html#GUID-87561B21-721C-42EB-8E3D-28251C9BC50C) if an outline was used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
alter system flush shared_pool;
```

Answer (score 1):

Flushing the sharedpool is just too risky operation to do on a whole system.
Rather consider using the following select statement

```
select ADDRESS, HASH_VALUE from V$SQLAREA where SQL_ID like '%';
```

and modify it to match the required criteria.
Then use dbms_package function procedure, to purge those execution plans.

```
exec DBMS_SHARED_POOL.PURGE ('< ADDRESS >, < HASH_VALUE', 'C');
```